# How can I trace mongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb

I'm running mongodb server as a windows service. How can i connect to it via console to trace executed queries?

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn on profiling:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

Then you can just query the system.profile collection to see the queries.